# Reduce A ∶= {x ∈ N ∣ x < 10} to Halting Problem on empty tape

Tags: reductions, halting-problem, semi-decidability, decidability

I am preparing for an exam in computability and still learning about the idea of reductions. I found an interesting problem to start with and am curious if my approach is correct:

**Let *H0* be the halting problem starting on an empty tape, and let A be a decision problem defined as A ∶= {x ∈ N ∣ x < 10}.
Show or disprove: A ⪯ H0.**

We show that A ⪯ H0 via mapping reduction. Proof:

A is decidable since it is finite (A = {0,...,9}). Moreover, A must then be semi-decidable, where *M* specifies a Turing machine that simulates the following semi-decidable procedure for A:

*M* := IF x ∈ {0,...,9} THEN OUTPUT(1); ELSE LOOP infinity;

Let f be a computable function that maps each input x to a Turing machine *M'* defined as follows:

*M'* := 
INPUT(ε) (i.e., *M'* starts on an empty tape) 
1.) Simulate *M* on x. 
2.) Halt. (i.e., accept x)

It now holds that x ∈ A ⇔ *M* halts on x ⇔ *M'* halts on ε ⇔ *M'* (=f(x)) ∈ *H0*.

q.e.d.

Any help or confirmation of correctness is appreciated as I am still trying to learn!

---